# set manual focus distance

Tags: focus

My nikon D3100 with 18-55 lense set to manual mode.
How do i set the focus to 10.5 meters as required for a landscape photo using Hyperfocus calculation.
The camera has a range setting for focus but does not show a distance scale.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a D3200, and as far as I know you can't do this because, as you mentioned, the lens does not have a distance scale.  It's not always possible, but you could measure from the sensor plane mark on the camera body to the desired distance using a measuring tape and focus on an object at that distance.

Comment: Thanks for your help.Stop aperture down and focus on required area of scene i guess plus trial and error.